# Most pythonic way to truncate a list to N indices when you can't guarantee the list is at least N length?

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to truncate a list to N indices when you can not guarantee the list is even N length?  Something like this:

```
l = range(6)

if len(l) > 4:
    l = l[:4]
```

I'm fairly new to python and am trying to learn to think pythonicly.  The reason I want to even truncate the list is because I'm going to enumerate on it with an expected length and I only care about the first 4 elements.

Comment: `list` is a built in type, it is best never to name your variables list because you are overriding that type.

Comment: You don't have to check. If the size of the list is smaller, the smaller sized list is returned.

Comment: @dm03514, Thanks for the reminder, I should have known better and have changed the example accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the answers so far *don't **truncate** the list*. They follow your example in assigning the name to a *new* list which contains the first up to 4 elements of the old list. To truncate the existing list, delete elements whose index is 4 or higher. This is done very simply:

```
del lst[4:]
```

Moving on to what you really want to do, one possibility is:

```
for i, value in enumerate(lst):
    if i >= 4:
        break
    do_something_with(lst, i, value)
```

Comment: You make a good point about my use of 'truncate'.  I actually don't care wether the list changes or not, but if I understand you correctly it is more memory efficient to simply use del to trim the current list down to size?

Comment: It's not about memory efficiency, it's about knowing what you really need to do then writing code that meets that need.

Answer (score 14):

Python automatically handles, the list indices that are out of range gracefully.

```
In [5]: k = range(2)

In [6]: k[:4]
Out[6]: [0, 1]

In [7]: k = range(6)

In [8]: k[:4]
Out[8]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

BTW, the degenerate slice behavior is explained in [The Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html). That is a good place to start because it covers a lot of concepts very quickly.

Comment: Ugh, of course your right about it being in the tutorial.  I went through it a long time ago, but just didn't retain that behavior knowledge.  Thanks for your patients.

Answer (score 5):

You've got it here:

```
lst = lst[:4]
```

This works regardless of the number of items in the list, even if it's less than 4.

If you want it to always have 4 elements, padding it with (say) zeroes or `None` if it's too short, try this:

```
lst = (lst + [0] * 4)[:4]
```

When you have a question like this, it's usually feasible to try it and see what happens, or look it up in the documentation.

It's bad idea to name a variable `list`, by the way; this will prevent you from referring to the built-in `list` type.

Comment: I guess the one thing I was wondering more then anything was if re-assigning a variable to a modified version of it's self was an efficient python solution.  John Machin solution of using del seems to make sense in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most pythonic solution that answers your question is this:

```
for x in l[:4]:
    do_something_with(x)
```

The advantages:

1. It's the most succinct and descriptive way of doing what you're after.
2. I suggest that the pythonic way to do this is to slice the source array rather than truncate it. Once you remove elements from the source array they are gone forever, and while in your trivial example that's fine, I think in general it's not a great practice.
3. Slicing the array to the first four is almost certainly more efficient than removing a possibly large number of elements from its tail.